# Search for all occurrences of a string in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to locate all occurrences of a url in a database. I want to search all tables and all fields. But I have no idea where to start or if it's even possible.

Comment: An example of when I needed this is when I needed to do a global find and replace on a database I was not familiar with, e.g. when migrating a WordPress site to a different domain I needed to replace all occurrences of the old domain name.

Comment: Refer this: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/mysql-search/

Comment: Export as text all tables, then Ctrl+F :)

Answer (score 248, accepted):

A simple solution would be doing something like this:

```sh
mysqldump -u myuser --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE databasename | grep -i "<search string>"
```

Comment: @SchlaWeiner that just dumps out the data; you have no idea the row schema or table.

Comment: http://www.adminer.org/ does a pretty good job looking for text in ALL tables (given specified database).

Comment: This makes sense if you are in a hurry ...

Comment: @ashes999 in `less` or `vim` you can search for next/prev occurrence of a DDL statement to find the table name. As for the row, it would find the row. Just look at the values and/or primary key in the matched line of text.

Comment: +1 I was trying to figure out a sql block to pass through all tables then all columns searching my string then do an update for that particular row.... WHAT A MESS!!! This is simple as ever!! Thank you so much!! Ps.: I already had the dump file and did not think about searching the string on it :P

Comment: This doesn't get me an ideal output. What gets returned is a `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2044810067, ...`. What are other people doing where this provides you with an organized output you can actually go through?

Comment: Found on a different answer that the flag you want is `--extended-insert=FALSE`. This makes the output MUCH more readable. Here's the answer I got it from (in the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4817152/293280

Comment: Pragmatic approach thus +1. This does not help someone who has binary fields in the DB though.

Comment: Quick and dirty and the only solution provided here that works for everyone.

Answer (score 136):

In **phpMyAdmin** a 'Search' feature is available:

1. Select particular database not table.
2. Click 'Search' tab
3. Enter the search term you want
4. Select the tables you want to search in

**phpMyAdmin** screen shot:

[image: phpMyAdmin Database Search tab]

The 'Search' feature is also available in **MySQL Workbench**:

1. Database Menu > Search Table Data
2. Select database and tables you want to search (it will search in selected tables only)
3. In search you can use wildChars.

**MySQL Workbench** screen shot:

[image: MySQL Workbench Database Search]

Comment: far better to extract dump file and search when dump is in a very big size

Comment: I just tried MySQLWorkbench version 6.3.9 on Mac os 10.12.6 and it has this 'global search' feature

Comment: Adminer (the one-PHP-file superfast (My)SQL tool has also a search feature (per database) - https://www.adminer.org/

Answer (score 64):

Old post I know, but for others that find this via Google like I did, if you have phpmyadmin installed, it has a global search feature.

Comment: What if you don't know the actual database?  Like OP, I need to find all instances of a specific IP address and I have 5+ GB of data in my MySQL db...

Comment: This feature has since been gone in the new versions of Phpmyadmin

Comment: I prefer HeidiSQL to phpMyAdmin. Same price, much easier to use and more powerful. Faster, too.

Comment: @pal4life - The feature is still there in phpadmin

Answer (score 28):

Using the MySQL Workbench, you can search for a string from the "Database" -> "Search Table Data" menu option.

Specify LIKE %URL_TO_SEARCH% and on the left side select all the tables you want to search through. You can use "Cntrl + A" to select the whole tree on the left, and then deselect the objects you don't care about.

[image]

Comment: Wow. I wish I knew of this answer 9 years ago.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) without generating Db dumps

**Steps**:

1. Select the database you need to search in from the left panel of GUI.
2. **Export > Export Database as SQL**
3. In Table Tools window, select "**FIND TEXT**" tab.
4. Provide your string to search and click "**FIND**".
5. It will list all the tables that has our string.
6. Select the row with higher **relevance %**.
7. Click "**SEE RESULTS**"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for this myself when we changed domain on our Wordpress website. It can't be done without some programming so this is what I did.

```
<?php  
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");

  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "mydatabase";
  $string_to_replace  = 'old.example.com';
  $new_string = 'new.example.com';

  // Connect to database server
  mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

  // Select database
  mysql_select_db($database);

  // List all tables in database
  $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$database;
  $tables_result = mysql_query($sql);

  if (!$tables_result) {
    echo "Database error, could not list tables\nMySQL error: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  echo "In these fields '$string_to_replace' have been replaced with '$new_string'\n\n";
  while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
    echo "Table: {$table[0]}\n";
    $fields_result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]);
    if (!$fields_result) {
      echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
      exit;
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($fields_result) > 0) {
      while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields_result)) {
        if (stripos($field['Type'], "VARCHAR") !== false || stripos($field['Type'], "TEXT") !== false) {
          echo "  ".$field['Field']."\n";
          $sql = "UPDATE ".$table[0]." SET ".$field['Field']." = replace(".$field['Field'].", '$string_to_replace', '$new_string')";
          mysql_query($sql);
        }
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
  }

  mysql_free_result($tables_result);  
?>
```

Hope it helps anyone who's stumbling into this problem in the future :)

Answer (score 6):

Found a way with two (2) easy codes [*here*](http://lookalive.co.uk/blog/searching-entire-database-string-mysqldump-and-grep). First do a [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html):

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > database-dump.sql
```

then [grep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) the sqldump file:

```
grep -i "Search string" database-dump.sql
```

It [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822691/4058484) also to [find/replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402972/4058484) and [re-import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666279/4058484) back to the database.

Comment: been using oracle/mysql (and others) for decades and I endorse the idea of dumping and using grep/sed/awk and reimporting. So much easier than the (you must admit this) somewhat quirky SQL language.

Answer (score 5):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) is GUI based solution to the problem of data search across all columns, tables and databases. One can customize search restricting it to field, table and databases.

In its `Data Search` feature one can search for strings just like one uses Google.

[image: SQLyog Datasearch screenshot]

Comment: But only ultimate version can do it. https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyogFeatureListExpanded

Answer (score 5):

MikeW presented an interesting solution, but as mentioned in comments, it's a SQL Server solution not a MySQL solution.  Here is a MySQL solution:

```
use information_schema;
set @q = 'Boston';
set @t = 'my_db';

select CONCAT('use \'',@q,'\';') as q UNION
select CONCAT('select \'', tbl.`TABLE_NAME`,'\' as TableName, \'', col.`COLUMN_NAME`,'\' as Col, `',col.`COLUMN_NAME`,'` as value  from `' , tbl.`TABLE_NAME`,'` where `' ,
        col.`COLUMN_NAME` , '` like \'%' ,@q,  '%\' UNION') AS q
from `tables` tbl
inner join `columns` col on tbl.`TABLE_NAME` = col.`TABLE_NAME`and col.DATA_TYPE='varchar'
where tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA  =  @t  ;
```

Comment: So close.  Some issues: 1. This produces a trailing `UNION` which is invalid.  2. Fourth line should be `select CONCAT('use \'',@t,'\';') as q UNION` 3. variables are ambiguous.  Might be better to call them `@search` and `@database`

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember where I came across this script, but I've been using it with XCloner to move my WP multisites.

```
<?php

    // Setup the associative array for replacing the old string with new string
    $replace_array = array( 'FIND' => 'REPLACE', 'FIND' => 'REPLACE');

    $mysql_link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' );
    if( ! $mysql_link) {
        die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
    }

    $mysql_db = mysql_select_db( 'DATABASE', $mysql_link );
    if(! $mysql_db ) {
        die( 'Can\'t select database: ' . mysql_error() );
    }

    // Traverse all tables
    $tables_query = 'SHOW TABLES';
    $tables_result = mysql_query( $tables_query );
    while( $tables_rows = mysql_fetch_row( $tables_result ) ) {
        foreach( $tables_rows as $table ) {

            // Traverse all columns
            $columns_query = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $table;
            $columns_result = mysql_query( $columns_query );
            while( $columns_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $columns_result ) ) {

                $column = $columns_row['Field'];
                $type = $columns_row['Type'];

                // Process only text-based columns
                if( strpos( $type, 'char' ) !== false || strpos( $type, 'text' ) !== false ) {
                    // Process all replacements for the specific column                    
                    foreach( $replace_array as $old_string => $new_string ) {
                        $replace_query = 'UPDATE ' . $table . 
                            ' SET ' .  $column . ' = REPLACE(' . $column . 
                            ', \'' . $old_string . '\', \'' . $new_string . '\')';
                        mysql_query( $replace_query );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result( $columns_result );
    mysql_free_result( $tables_result );
    mysql_close( $mysql_link );

    echo 'Done!';

?>
```

Comment: http://www.brilliantsheep.com/replacing-a-string-in-all-tables-of-a-database-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a bash - here is a script:
It needs a user dbread with pass dbread on the database.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
DBUSER=dbread
DBPASS=dbread
echo -n "Which database do you want to search in (press 0 to see all databases): " 
read DB
echo -n "Which string do you want to search: " 
read SEARCHSTRING
for i in `mysql $DB -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -e "show tables" | grep -v \`mysql $DB -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -e "show tables" | head -1\``
do
for k in `mysql $DB -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -e "desc $i" | grep -v \`mysql $DB -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -e "desc $i" | head -1\` | grep -v int | awk '{print $1}'`
do
if [ `mysql $DB -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS -e "Select * from $i where $k='$SEARCHSTRING'" | wc -l` -gt 1 ]
then
echo " Your searchstring was found in table $i, column $k"
fi
done
done
```

If anyone wants an explanation: http://infofreund.de/?p=1670

Answer (score 1):

Scott gives a good example of how to do it, but the question is why would you want to?  If you need to do a find-and-replace on a specific string, you could also try doing a mysqldump of your database, do a find-and-replace in an editor, then re-load the database.

Maybe if you gave some background on what you are trying to achieve, others might be able to provide better answers.

Comment: There are cases where that won't work, or might not be a good idea. Example: query all rows in a database that contain a certain string among user-submitted HTML code, then load those rows into an HTML parser, manipulate the data, and re-save them.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same but couldn't find it, so I make a small script in PHP, you can find it at:
http://tequilaphp.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/searching-strings-in-a-database-and-files/

Good luck!
(I remove some private code, let me know if I didn't break it in the process :D)

Comment: Thanks for that! you saved me time! I would like it more if I had the option to set case sensitive search :)

Answer (score 1):

The first 30 seconds of this video shows how to use the global search feature of Phpmyadmin
and it works. it will search every table for a string.

http://www.vodahost.com/vodatalk/phpmyadmin-setup/62422-search-database-phpmyadmin.html

Answer (score 1):

In unix machines, if the database is not too big:

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> <database_name> --extended=FALSE | grep <String to search> | less -S
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but you could achieve it with a nested looping structure

```
// select tables from database and store in an array

// loop through the array
foreach table in database
{
    // select columns in the table and store in an array

    // loop through the array
    foreach column in table
    {
        // select * from table where column = url
    }
}
```

You could probably speed this up by checking which columns contain strings while building your column array, and also by combining all the columns per table in one giant, comma-separated WHERE clause.

Comment: <code>where column like '%url%'</code> if you can't guarantee the field is just the URL.