# how to check whether a data exists in multiple mysql tables on different fields

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named A and B

table A-
id1 id2 id3 id4

table B-
id5 id6 id7 id8

I want to check whether a data exists in table A on field id1 or in table B on fields id6 or id7

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple options exist for sub-string search in MySQL

- One often overlooked option: if you are using or have access to a database client, such as Navicat, you can use the `Find in database ...` search
- There are other options as well as indicated in the see also links

#### See also

- [Navicat find in database](https://www.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/win_manual/FindDB.html)
- [Other database sub-string search options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384245/way-to-search-entire-database-for-a-string-in-mysql#1384254)