# Generate table DDL via query on MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, database, ddl

Is there an easy way to extract table DDL information, via a query, using either Ms or My SQL server?  (preferably both?)

For example, using MySQL Administrator / Navicat for MySql, there is a "DDL" function, which generates the "create table foo (....)" script.

Is there any way to get this information from a query itself, such as:

```
Select DDL from foo where table_name='bar';
```

Any have the "Create table bar (.....)" returned to me?

If not - any suggestions?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

it's mysql-specific, but `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table-name>` gives you the DDL for a table.

Comment: Upvoted. Just to be more specific about the syntax, it would be `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`.

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Can we get the DDL also for entire schema?

Answer (score 5):

You have to create that yourself.

You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for the column name and data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the `CREATE Table` text in a cross platform way, but you can get enough information to build it yourself from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

These queries generate results that you can copy and paste or use to automate:

Queries based off of ["Search text in fields in every table of a MySQL database"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647016/1896134)

```
-- KEY
-- CHAR(96) IS BACKTICK
-- CHAR(46) IS PERIOD
-- CHAR(59) IS SEMI-COLON
```

### Tables

```sql
SELECT
CONCAT('SHOW CREATE TABLE '
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `TABLE_SCHEMA`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(46) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `TABLE_NAME`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(59) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
      ) AS QUERY_GENERATOR
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE
      UPPER(`TABLE_SCHEMA`)
        NOT IN (
                'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
              , 'MYSQL'
              , 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
              , 'SAKILA'
              , 'SYS'
              , 'WORLD'
               )
  AND UPPER(`TABLE_TYPE`) = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY 1;
```

### Views

```sql
SELECT
CONCAT('SHOW CREATE VIEW '
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `TABLE_SCHEMA`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(46) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `TABLE_NAME`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(59) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
      ) AS QUERY_GENERATOR
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE
      UPPER(`TABLE_SCHEMA`)
        NOT IN (
                'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
              , 'MYSQL'
              , 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
              , 'SAKILA'
              , 'SYS'
              , 'WORLD'
               )
  AND UPPER(`TABLE_TYPE`) = 'VIEW'
ORDER BY 1
;
```

### Stored Procedures/Routines

```
SELECT
CONCAT('SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE '
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `ROUTINE_SCHEMA`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(46) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1), `ROUTINE_NAME`, CAST(CHAR(96) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
     , CAST(CHAR(59) AS CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN1)
      ) AS QUERY_GENERATOR
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES`
WHERE
      UPPER(`ROUTINE_SCHEMA`)
        NOT IN (
                'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
              , 'MYSQL'
              , 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
              , 'SAKILA'
              , 'SYS'
              , 'WORLD'
               )
ORDER BY 1
;
```