# Create To script for a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I have a global temporary table in SQL Server 2008 R2. I need a script generated the same way we generate the scripts through "**Script table as**" -> "**Create to**" in SSMS.

I didn't actually create the temporary table. I'm simply trying to use its schema to create a table so I can permanently store the data in my table during a transaction.

Comment: You want a script to do what exactly?

Comment: You can look here.. similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537951/generate-table-ddl-via-query-on-mysql-and-sql-server

Comment: @samyi did you read those answers? Not very useful for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table

Comment: @AaronBertrand, my apologies.  Can't you do "select * into " then use SSMS to generate?

Comment: Why are you using a global temporary table? What advantage does this have over a permanent table? Both reduce concurrency to exactly 1.

Comment: `SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [anotherdb].[dbo].[formerly_global_table_temp] from ##global_temp_table;` and script that out?? i guess that's my best suggestion. also, +1 to the comment from @AaronBertrand

Comment: You can also query this table to generate the script yourself. tempdb.information_schema.columns where table_name = '##tablename'

Comment: Judging by your requirements what you should do is make a table instead.

Comment: (sorry ... i thought you wanted data too)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answer. I didn't actually create the temporary table. I'm simply trying to use its schema to create a table so I can permanently store the data in my table during a transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the SSMS GUI to do this. But this code was taken from [In SQL Server, how do I generate a CREATE TABLE statement for a given table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table)

```
select  'create table [' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'ALTER TABLE ' + so.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')' END
from    sysobjects so
cross apply
    (SELECT 
        '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
        data_type + case data_type
            when 'sql_variant' then ''
            when 'text' then ''
            when 'ntext' then ''
            when 'xml' then ''
            when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
            else coalesce('('+case when character_maximum_length = -1 then 'MAX' else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end +')','') end + ' ' +
        case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=so.name
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
        ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
         (case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
          case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT ELSE '' END + ', ' 

     from information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name
     order by ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)
left join
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
on  tc.Table_name       = so.Name
AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
cross apply
    (select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
     FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     WHERE  kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
     ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION
     FOR XML PATH('')) j (list)
where   xtype = 'U'
AND name    NOT IN ('dtproperties')
```

Comment: Is that the right link?  I don't see anything like this there.

Comment: oups, I changed it for the right one