# Is there a way to search all fields in a single mysql query?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [MYSQL query for searching through ALL the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797906/mysql-query-for-searching-through-all-the-fields)
>   [MySQL - Search in all fields from every table from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database)

I have 28 fields in a table and one option I would like to give a user is to search every entry across all its fields. 
So Instead of writing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE testfield OR field2 LIKE testfield OR field3 LIKE testfield 
OR field4 LIKE testfield OR  ... etc
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * LIKE testfield;
```

This doesnt work so I wondering if there is another syntax or the feature doesnt exist?

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797906/mysql-query-for-searching-through-all-the-fields that links to another similar question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database

Comment: The question SpyrosP has linked to has the better answers of the two.

Answer (score 0):

There's no portable support for this type of query in SQL. Your best bet is to create another string/varchar column and concat the other columns into a string and then search on that.

SQL Server does support a [*contains* keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142488.aspx):

```
SELECT Name, Color FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS((Name, Color), 'Red');
```

But, if you want to be portable, you're better off with the extra column.

Comment: That would force a full table scan then. ]