# Search all fields in mySql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search all fields from  tables​​ tblproduct in MySQL database a given string, possibly using syntax as:

`SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE * LIKE '%textbox%'`

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: you mean search on ALL columns

Comment: its Full Text search. And this question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797906/mysql-query-for-searching-through-all-the-fields

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE (CONVERT(<column name> USING utf8) LIKE '%textbox%' OR CONVERT(<column name> USING utf8) LIKE '%textbox%' OR .........`

Comment: Check the technique shown in this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834912/sql-search-for-a-string-in-every-varchar-column-in-a-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

concate fields to search whole table

```
Select * from tblproduct  where Concat(field1, '', field2, '', fieldn) like "%textbox%"
```

or

Using MATCH and AGAINST in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM tblproduct  WHERE MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST ('textbox')
```