# mySQL query to search all tables within a database for a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

**Is there a mySQL query to search all tables within a database?**

If not can you search all tables within a database from the mySQL workbench GUI?

From phpmyadmin there's a search panel you can use to **select all tables** to search through.  I find this super effective since magento, the ecommerce package I'm working with has hundreds of tables and different product details are in different tables.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I recommend add line SET sql_notes = 0$$ before DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_table $$ Otherwise it will show warning `PROCEDURE` does not exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do it purely in MySQL, without the help of any programming language, you could use this:

```
## Table for storing resultant output

CREATE TABLE `temp_details` (
 `t_schema` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `t_table` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `t_field` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

## Procedure for search in all fields of all databases
DELIMITER $$
#Script to loop through all tables using Information_Schema
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_table(in_search varchar(50))
 READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 DECLARE trunc_cmd VARCHAR(50);
 DECLARE search_string VARCHAR(250);

 DECLARE db,tbl,clmn CHAR(50);
 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE COUNTER INT;

 DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR
 SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` WHERE `', column_name,'` REGEXP ''',in_search,''';')
 ,table_schema,table_name,column_name
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','test','mysql');

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

 #Truncating table for refill the data for new search.
 PREPARE trunc_cmd FROM "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_details;";
 EXECUTE trunc_cmd ;

 OPEN table_cur;
 table_loop:LOOP
 FETCH table_cur INTO search_string,db,tbl,clmn;

 #Executing the search
 SET @search_string = search_string;
 SELECT search_string;
 PREPARE search_string FROM @search_string;
 EXECUTE search_string;


 SET COUNTER = @CNT_VALUE;
 SELECT COUNTER;

 IF COUNTER>0 THEN
 # Inserting required results from search to table
 INSERT INTO temp_details VALUES(db,tbl,clmn);
 END IF;

 IF done=1 THEN
 LEAVE table_loop;
 END IF;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE table_cur;

 #Finally Show Results
 SELECT * FROM temp_details;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Source: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=232

Comment: Old post but I was looking for something like this too but have not used MySQL functions or procedures before to any extent. The OP was looking for something to search all tables within a database but this procedure seems to search all databases. How can it be limited to just the one in which it resides?

Comment: It works little different, bacause it returns array with search_string = query (query in LOOP).
But when I comment lines: SELECT search_string; and SELECT COUNTER; , then it works well as expected and procedure return right content.
Its maybe due DB version, my is MariaDB 10.1.31.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, if your database is not that huge, you can make a dump and make your search in the .sql generated file.

Comment: This indeed was my preferred way, directly from command line (so not logged in using sql> prompt). More on this here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html And then you can easily search using grep "search terms" ~/backup.sql

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **MySQL Workbench**, you can do this by doing right click on the DB Schema you want to search into, and then "**Search Table Data...**".

In there you can select the "**Search using REXEXP**" option, and then type your text of search as usual. It will provide the DB rows matching your specific text.

You will need to check the **"Search columns of all types"** box as well.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench you can use the [Table Data Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-table-search.html) feature. It can search across multiple tables and/or multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Search string in all tables on a database is a complex task. Normally you don't need to use exactly all tables and results are complex to read without a specific layout (tree of tables with matches or the like)

[SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/downloads.html) offers a GUI and a command-line version to do such task:

More info:

- http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-search-data
- http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/dbexplorer.html#search-table-data

**NOTE:** Search with JDBC driver uses a lot of memory if it is not configured properly. SQL Workbench/J warns about that and although online documentation is a bit outdated, the sources of documentation (doc/xml/db-problems.xml) explain how to fix it for different BBDD:

Here an extract for Postgres:

> The PostgreSQL JDBC driver defaults to buffer the results obtained from the database
>           in memory before returning them to the application. This means that when retrieving data, &wb-productname; uses (for a short amount of time) twice as much memory as really needed. This also means that WbExport or WbCopy will
>           effectively read the entire result into memory before writing it into the output file.
>           For large exports, this is usually not wanted.
>   This behavior of the driver can be changed so that the driver uses cursor based retrieval.
>           To do this, the connection profile must disable the "Autocommit" option and must define a default fetch size that is greater than zero. A recommended value is e.g. 10, it might be that higher numbers give a better performance. The number defined for the fetch size,
>           defines the number of rows the driver keeps in its internal buffer before requesting more
>           rows from the backend.