# Search all tables using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can I search all tables for a string with the MySQL GUI?

Or is something like this: [mySQL query to search all tables within a database for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string) the only solution?

Comment: It would be advisable to accept the answer from old_mountain.

Comment: Done - thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.

> From the `Schema Tree`, choose the tables and/or schemas you want to search, right click and then select `Search Data Table`... from the context menu.

The search has some options:

> Search for table fields that: `"CONTAINS"`, `"Search using ="`, `"Search using LIKE"`, `"Search using REGEXP"`. These search options are case-insensitive.

[image]

You can get more information in the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-table-search.html).