# Search for a value in all tables in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

I can't find a search function with which I can search all tables in a database for a certain value in DataGrip.

This functionality does exist in other database tools, see:

- [PhpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841554/3143953)
- [MySQl Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413220/3143953)
- [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=1006)

I don't know how to achieve similiar functionality with DataGrip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Version 2019.2 of DataGrip supports full text searches.

1. select datasources, schemas or even separate tables in Database view
2. select Full-text Search in context menu
3. enter query and hit enter

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-87#focus=streamItem-27-3621219.0-0

Answer (score 3):

It is supported. In short, `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F` should work. For detail, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/full-text-search-for-databases.html.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED: Full-text search is supported from the version 2019.2**