# search for a string, inside columns with a text-like type, in all tables whose name contains another string

Tags: mysql

The DB I'm working on has roughly 30 tables that might contain different pieces of data I'd like to locate.  Not an ideal situation but hey ho.

Given two strings...

- `string1` - value that appears in table name.
- `string2` - value to be searched for text-like columns.

...I'd like to search all tables with name matching `string1` for columns that have a datatype in...

- text
- char
- varchar

... for data rows `like "%string2%"`.

What I'd ideally see returned is a resultset with a row for each `string1`, `string2` hit, in a format like:

- table_name_string1_appears_in
- colum_name_string2_appears_in
- value_from_id_col_of_table_with_name_like_string1
- data_from_cell_matching_string2

Can a pure mysql solution exist for this that is re-usable?

Comment: this would have to be a dynamic query built using `information_schema`. Have you tried to write it?

Comment: Some SQL clients offer this kind of tools. Which one are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL query to search all tables within a database for a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I am investigating.  @a_horse, my mysql client is the the mysql CLI :)  `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1`. @echo_me. The answer by @entropid in the linked question looks like good building blocks, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A php-workaround (not pure sql) is to have your 30 tables' name to be stored on an array.
foreach each of them and evaluate whether the table name is part of your aray value. If it's true, then run a `%string2%`  select query on that table name

Comment: Thanks Willy, I'm hoping some SQL can do the lot.  I've encountered this situation a few times before, but seem to overcome it in a unique way each time.  I've always previously used another language...

Answer (score 0):

if you want search for string in all your database

then do this

```
   mysqldump -u myuser --no-create-info databasename > myfile.sql
```

and after find your string in myfile.sql

or try this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string)