# How to fetch data from either of tables based on input query

Tags: php, mysql

I had to normalize my db as it was so intense that couldn't get required search results.
Now I have 10 tables and I am looking around some way that if visiter inputs query that matches with any one of 10 tables, data should be requested from that one (Anyways I have normalized it the way that query cannot be from multiple tables)

I tried:

```
("SELECT * FROM tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4... WHERE vbc LIKE..
```

That doesn't seem to work, And I guess UNION/JOINS are not worth as I want to fetch data fron either of the table. Look forward for your suggestion. Thanks.

What I have:

Table1

```
id  planet  areas
1   Earth   USA
2   Earth   Canada
3   Earth   Mexico
4   Earth   UK
```

Table2

```
id  Area    Flowers
1   USA     Roses
2   USA     Lily
3   USA     Lotus
4   USA     Alyssum
```

If only use table1, and enter 'Earth' in search I get all name of countries and if I enter 'USA' I get USA in result.. And thats what I want..
But can't seem to do it with multiple tables..

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to use `Union`.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: If you could dump your db schema it would help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string

Comment: Hi thanks I just added further details to show you what exactly I want..