# MySql search for an email across all tables in database

Tags: mysql

We have more than 40 tables under a database called "Coredata" and tables named from 't001', 't002' to 't040'. All table has one common field - 'email' so building a search option using 'email' as a key index, so following is my SQL query to search between few tables - please suggest an easy approach to run the query and search/fetch data across all 40 tables.

Following query pops-up **#1052 - Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous**

```
 SELECT * from t001, t002 WHERE email ="emailid@gmail.com";
```

Comment: I would advise you to create a view once with hardcoded UNION all from all tables. Then you can use it like you use on big table.

Comment: I think your database schema should have a master table for all emails where the email is a primary key.  Without this, I'd say your schema has a smell.

Comment: @Lamar That might work, but it would probably not be too performant since indices could not be used on the subquery.

Comment: You missed a `JOIN`  between your 2 tables. That's why it is said **where clause is ambigous**. Email from table t001 or t002 ? or Both ? it's your error to not specify the Table. Especially if the email column exists in both tables.

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string