# How to Update all Dates in a Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 5 million `DATETIME` records. I want to add a year to all the various datetimes in the table. Can I do it all with a single query? Something like:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(*, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Or any other way you would recommend. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
UPDATE table SET datefield = DATE_ADD(datefield, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

If you need to update every table in the database check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database)

Comment: He wants to do it for *all* datetime fields in the whole database.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - This WILL update all records in a given table. In order to update every table without knowing the table names you'll have to first run the query "SHOW TABLES" then work off the results from that.

Comment: Yes, it will update the "datefield" field in all records.  However, his question is much more general, and will probably require use of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: Sorry, I should be clearer. I just need it for one table. Thanks.

Comment: Thank a lot Pastor