# Rails 3 update_all using data already contained in the table on a per-record basis

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, update-all

This is vaguely related to: 
[How to Update all Dates in a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365474/how-to-update-all-dates-in-a-table)
But only if you squint real hard.

Part 1 - I know that SQL can update one column on a table based on a formula that involves other columns on that same table.  And it can be done with a single, simple line of SQL as follows:

```
UPDATE thieving_prices SET current_price = (1 + usury_rate) * current_price;
```

Now all prices have just been hiked by their various associated villainous rates.

Part 2 - I also know that Rails 3 offers a wonderful bit of magic called update_all which creates an UPDATE query using a single line of SQL:

```
ThievingPrice.update_all(:current_price = 35000.00)
```

generates:

```
UPDATE thieving_prices SET current_price = 35000.00;
```

Now all of the prices are identical for all products.  Very useless in this sneaky store.

Part 3 - All of these prices have their own steady rates of increase and there aught to be a way to write an elegant line of code in Rails 3 to accomplish it.

And the line:

```
ThievingPrice.update_all(:current_price => (1 + :usury_rate) * :current_price)
```

doesn't work.  Nor does any syntactic variation involving parenthesis, braces or brackets--so far as my experiments have shown. Surely others have come across a need for such a construction.  I don't want to fall back on the incredibly slow and resource-wasting each block:

```
ThievingPrice.each do |tp|
  new_price = tp.current_price * (1 + tp.usury_rate)
  tp.update_attribute(:current_price => new_price)
end
```

By the time that finishes my <strike>victims</strike> patrons have left the store.  What are my options?

Comment: Does `ThievingPrice.update_all("current_price = (1 + ?) * current_price" , :usury_rate)` fail?

Comment: No, it tries to multiply by the string 'usury_rate'

Comment: But, because it is based on data that has already been verified before being stored in the database, I can safely vary your suggestion as follows: ThievingPrice.update_all("current_price = (1 + #{:usury_rate}) * current_price)  and that does work.  Thank you for helping me see it in a different way.

Comment: Could you put that into an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: Even better, it would appear that I don't have to escape the quotes at all.  Which makes sense because this would feed cleanly into SQL: ThievingPrice.update_all("current_price = (1 + usury_rate) * current_price")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `ThievingPrice.update_all("current_price = (1 + ?) * current_price" , :usury_rate)`. it should take the parameter and multiply the current price by that amount based on the object being updated at the moment.