# MySQL tool that searches for a string in all fields, tables and databases

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - Search in all fields from every table from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database)

I am looking for some MySQL GUI tool, that searches for a string in all databases/ tables/ fields. I have tried Toad, MySQL Workbench and HeidiSQL, It seems none has this feature.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @juergen d... I am not looking for any query, I am just looking for some tool, that performs the task that i want.

Comment: have you looked at the answers? There are tools mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I just checked out, there is mention of SQLyog, phpMyAdmin and a google code link.

Answer (score 0):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). I have tried search among all tables in a Database. it use to Search globally in a database or a subset of it.

Comment: But it seems for phpMyAdmin, I need to have some Apache server or something like that to be installed to get phpMyAdmin to get to work. MySQL is installed on my local machine.

Comment: right.. you can install it separately or using `xampp` that will install all the needs itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try Find Object feature in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Start dbForge Studio, run `Find Object` window (menu Database\Find Object...), enter `Find What` string, check `Search table data`, select all databases in `Database` combobox, and click `Search` button.