# Procedure which searching UserId in all tables in databases

Tags: mysql, search, int, procedure

I want writing a procedure in MySQL which searching a UserId which we write example

```
call NEW_PROCEDURE(2)
```

`where 2 = UserId` which we want search in all tables. I have an idea but I dont know how do it. First we must search all columns in database where `column_name = UserId` and Second we must search a value that we called in the procedure and `UserId = our value`

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Hope following links will help you

[StackOverflow Similar Question #1][1]

[StackOverflow Similar Question #2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624611/mysql-tool-that-searches-for-a-string-in-all-fields-tables-and-databases
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an idea http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10883/search-a-value-in-character-column-of-all-tables.aspx

```
1 Use concat instead of +
2 Use prepared statement to exeucte the query
3 Information_schema is supported in mysql too
```