# How to search a particular word in all databases in my mysql server?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have 780 databases in my mysql server. 
All the databases contain `wp_options` table. I need to search a particular word in all the databases inside that `wp_options` table. 
Is there any methods to do that?
And all my databases start with a prefix `common_phrase"_"db_name`, for example:

```
phrase_db1, phrase_db2, phrase_db3 ...
```

Please suggest me some ideas to do that.

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)