# How can I find a value in a DB when I don't know the table, row or field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've inherited a database with 233 tables and somewhere in there product serial numbers are kept track of and I need to find out where. My thought was to buy a product and see the serial number I'm issued and then somehow search every field of every row of every table for that value.  Is there a way to do this quickly with phpMyAdmin?   Thanks.

Comment: Export every datas then search in the .sql file created (using NotePad++ or textEditor). Just use the search tool

Comment: Did you inherit a schema with the database? Also, what's the naming convention like of your tables? That should narrow it down by quite a bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: Use the query tool in `phpmyadmin`. You can make queries on every tables

Comment: I found the answer in Greg Lyon's answer in  the 639531 post in Hearner's comment above.  phpMyAdmin lets you search all the tables within a database. This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` will return metadata information on every table.

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` will return metadata information on every column.