# Search for specific string/pattern in MySQL Database from Terminal/SSH/Commandline

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a Magento database in which I want to search for a particular `string/pattern`.

But the database's size is too large so I cannot export the database to `.sql` file and then search into that file(editor even Geany crashes opening such large files).

So how can I do a search the database for a perfect match of [string/pattern] and display `fulltext` information as result, through only using command-line and MySQL Database credentials ?

I tried below command, but it requires `username` to be given as `-u[USERNAME]`, also it doesn't display full query or result in terminal window.

```
mysqldump -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE] --extended=FALSE | grep [pattern] | less -S
```

Anyone have any solutions for this ?

Comment: If you have the data in a database, then why don't you use sql to search the data? Mysql does have a command line client.

Comment: mysql -u [USERNAME] -p [password] -e 'SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE field = pattern'

Comment: There are a hell lot of tables in a Magento database (atleast over 135), so I don't think that's a faster option, that's why I asked for searching in `database` rather than `column` or `table`. Thanks for effor though.

Comment: It is clearly explained what I need in the question, and in some situations this is what is only thing needed, so the downvoter must be unaware and non-experienced of those situations.

Comment: @VickyDev - You didn't clearly explain. When you say "that's why I asked for searching in database rather than column or table" I can't see anywhere in the question where you asked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can first log into MySQL CLI as especified in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb
```

So, you can use a query command to find your pattern. If you know the table you want to search such as the column it make the thinks easy. The SELECT statement is like this:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%pattern%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html

If you don't know the table's name, you can list all and try to find by the meaning.

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Comment: There are a hell lot of tables in a Magento database (atleast over 135), so I don't think that's a faster option, that's why I asked for searching in `database` rather than `column` or `table`. Thanks for effor though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database I think that there is no easy way to peform what you want. Could you give more information what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited with better code**

You didn't say if this was a one off or not but this will check all tables in a schema for a value.

First in your home directory set up a file named .my.cnf with the following contents and change its permissions to 700 (Replace [USERNAME] and [PASSWORD] with your username and password.

```
[client]
user=[USERNAME]
password="[PASSWORD]"
```

Then execute the following (Replacing [DATABASE] and [CHECKSTRING] with your database and the check string)

```
mysql [DATABASE] --silent -N -e "show tables;"|while read table; do mysql [DATABASE] --silent -N -e "select * from ${table};"|while read line;do if [[ "${line}" == *"[CHECKSTRING]"* ]]; then echo "${table}***${line}";fi;done;done
```

If checking for 51584 the result would be something like

```
test_table***551584,'column 2 value','column 3 value'
test_table5***'column 1 value',251584,'column 3 value'
```

If you want to know which column had the value then select from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and add another nest.

```
mysql [DATABASE] --silent -N -e "show tables;"|while read table; do mysql [DATABASE] --silent -N -e "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='[DATABASE]' and table_name = '${table}';"|while read column; do mysql [DATABASE] --silent -N -e "select ${column} from ${table};"|while read line;do if [[ "${line}" == *"[CHECKSTRING]"* ]]; then echo "${table}***${column}***${line}";fi;done;done;done
```

If checking for 51584 the result would be something like

```
test_table***column1***551584
test_table5***column2***251584
```

Comment: Whe I run your command I get message `Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Even though I provided correct username and password.

Comment: Updated the response to include creating a .my.cnf file.   This file allows you to run mysql command line commands without having to enter in a username and password.  Remove it once you are done if this is on a production machine.

Comment: `@KepBrown` It' a live site, with cpanel and `/home/user/public_html` folder. Where should I put this my.cnf file, will permissions 700 apply ?

Comment: In that case replace

Comment: replace all instances of mysql [DATABASE] with mysql --user=[USERNAME] --password=[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to login into database with correct username and password by below command.

sudo mysql -u root -p

then check the database in which you want to operate operation.
eg.

SHOW DATABASES;

USE Test;

now your database is ready for operation through terminal. Here I assume my database name is "Test".

Now for String/pattern matching use command as below  or follow the link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx.

**SELECT 
    column_list
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    string_column REGEXP pattern;**