# Most efficient way to search multiple tables for one value

Tags: mysql, search

I'm trying to search for one value against 3 tables e.g.

user searches for 'test'

'test' needs to be a where clause for 3 tables. I could do it like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `field` = "test";
SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `field` = "test";
SELECT * FROM `table3` WHERE `field` = "test";
```

but that seems like it could be simplified, any thoughts?
Not searching information_schema for data.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)