# How to search table names in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, database, search

Could anybody give me a little advice as to how I would search the table names from 1 database within a SQL PHP query.

At present this is my not working code.

I have a database named classified  with a list of genres ie `computers` `clothes` `cars` `music` etc etc. Within each table is. I'd name price etc etc. I have all that processing correctly and I can use the data in my webpage but I'm a little stuck on the searching. Here's my query code:

```
Select * from $dbname WHERE $results LIKE '%$search%'
```

Comment: A database or table? Where is your code?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    sys.tables 
WHERE
    name
LIKE
    '%product%'
```

Comment: or are you asking how to use that query?

Comment: My query dont work. That's just expressing what I'm trying to do.. Use the list of genres in the dbname to search.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to perform a full database search to find out a data you can easily use MySql workbench or PhpMyAdmin to search data from your database. Also there are many open posts on StackOverflow regarding this issues. Please read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234937/4465528) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database).