# How to search a database

Tags: mysql, search

I am asking this question as general purpose. I wanted to know how searching a database works, suppose I have a certain tag or word with me and I want to get all the rows in which that tag is present and the database is MySQL. what could be possible and fastest ways to do this. Do I need to shift to NoSQL for this?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do this with any relational database (and most NoSQL databases as well).  But your question is too broad, and perhaps you should review a good SQL tutorial.

Comment: [Have a looksy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

### Mysql search Query

```
tag = "english";

// suppose tag is certain field name in table 

SQL query = SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%english%';
```