# Global search with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I wrote a code to search in within a data table whereby entering a id and customer name but i need to search extra field without specifying the column.

I need to search by column, there's the controller with Search function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $output = "";
            $indents = DB::table('indents')
                ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orwhere('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orwhere('*', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search. '%')
                ->get();
                $count=1;
            foreach ($indents as $key => $indent) {


                    $output .= '<tr>' .
                    '<td>'.$count++.'</td>'.
//                    '<td>' . $indent->id . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $indent->customer_name . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $indent->phone_no . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $indent->date_of_delivery . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $indent->delivery_at . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . '.<a href="' . route('edp.show', $indent->id) . '">.' . '<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.' . '</a>.' . '</td>' .
                    '</tr>';

            }
            return Response($output);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array of columns to search in like this:

`$columnsToSearch = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'];`

These columns can be part of the `$request` if you need it to be passed from the frontend/api.

Then loop through each `$columnsToSearch` and add to your query builder like so:

```
$columnsToSearch = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'];
// or $columnsToSearch = $request->input('columns_to_search');

$searchQuery = '%' . $request->search . '%';

$indents = DB::table('indents')
            ->where('id', 'LIKE', $searchQuery);

foreach($columnsToSearch as $column) {
    $indents = $indents->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', $searchQuery);
}

$indents = $intents->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Scount [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout)

Or you can implement yourself, using mysql [Mysql Full-text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all table columns with:

```
$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('indents');
```

Then for each column add orwhere() condition. Beware though, the search will be slow for big tables, unless you add indexing.