# Search in MYSQL DATABASE Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the database named mydatabase_db & it has round about 12-15 tables.Suppose I don't have/know the names of the tables & want to search a word that may be any string with in the database i.e. mydatabase_db.Now my question is that I want to search the string in the whole database not in a specific table.
Kindly share the solution if any have the key.

Comment: a member with more than 4 years SO experience should be able to find this question here - possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @sintakonte thank you for guidance.

Comment: why will you need that? specially why would you need to iterate of all the tables?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo actually my requirement is like that I want to search a string in the whole database instead of querying from each table.

Comment: export it, open it in notepad and search it? i hope you are doing it for yourself as you would not need anything like that in programming

Comment: Sir @DanyalSandeelo actually my website has the search option if the user want to search something then he/she searched that.These are Client requirements.

Comment: then why do you want to make this thing dynamic, you know where the data is located and the content is available. just search those tables and those columns.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo you are right but if I dont want this technique then what will be the possible solution.