# Can I filter result in mySQL without knowing table nor column I am searching in?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am having an issue for formulating this question, but this is essentially what I want. Once connecting to a database I want to search for something which could be in any table inside any column.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where column='123456789'
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM [AllTablesInDatabase] where [AllColumnsInDatabase]='%123456789%'
```

I feel like this is a common question, but I can't seem to formulate it in a way that I can find the answer to this. I am using mySQL, 8.0 I believe, just trying to see what I can do in it. I can see that I likely can just output a list of a huge database's tables and columns and just paste it, but that is going to be an extremely long statement.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-text-in-fields-in-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: A database typically stores each table in one or more files.  So when you say search all tables/files, you're in effect searching all data files related to the database.  So you will likely need to iterate though all tables to search all files.  such a task will not be performant.   The method would be a stored procedure which uses the system tables to iterate though the list of tables/fields and executes a query looking at each for the desired value.  Now you don't define the expected results so are you after the table/field key which contains the result?