# How to find a speicifc entry in tables in a database mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a database wordpress consisting a lot of tables. I am looking for a certain entry `20.22.31.44`. What is the best way to return the table and column if this entry exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search text in fields in every table of a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-text-in-fields-in-every-table-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @GuilhermeMaia Thank you. I was able to do it using mysql workbench. If you still however add this as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump your database data (`SQLDump`) into a file and search through it's content.

You may also use a Database Management system (i.e. Workbench, PHPMyAdmin) to perform that global search for you. [See related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-text-in-fields-in-every-table-of-a-mysql-database).