# Select any field from any table

Tags: mysql

is it possible for a mysql statement to select any field from any table ?
for example : 
`SELECT * FROM * WHERE ? IN (SELECT * FROM *)` to implement a generic search method which doesn't depends on a specific table or field. i've just read that we can list all tables of a database with a, SQL command : `SHOW TABLES`
Do you have any idea about how can we do this ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Does it have to be only in sql or you can use something like php?

Comment: This is covered in this post, there are multiple solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: Thank you @Marc :) No, it can be in PHP (but only in PHP because i'm working with it)

Comment: @mikeswright49 : thank you ! i'm reading that post now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this in php

```
$getTables = mysql_query("show tables");
$tmpString = '';
while ($table_data = mysql_fetch_row($getTables))
{
    $tmpString.=$table_data[0].',';
}   
$ALL_DATABASE_TABLES = substr($string,0,strlen($tmpString)-1); //Remove the last ,
```

Then you got all your tables and you can build your query

like this

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM $ALL_DATABASE_TABLES"
```

Comment: Actually, it's not a elegant way but it will work ;) Glad to help

Comment: I'm gonna use it while searching for a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure and use dynamic query mechanism e.g. below:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dynamicQuery()
  BEGIN
  SET @tableName := 'TABLENAME1';
  SET @SqlStr = 'SELECT  * FROM @tableName';
  PREPARE n_StrSQL FROM @SqlStr;
  EXECUTE n_StrSQL;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE n_StrSQL;
 END
```

Comment: Thank you :) but it's like if i do : `SELECT * FROM table1, table2, ...., table200 WHERE ? IN (SELECT * FROM table1, table2, ...., table200);` isn't it ?

Comment: @Mehdi: No, its like running `select * from Table1` or `select * from Table2`. All I meant to say is that you can construct a dynamic query sing variables and execute them. Its up to you, what query you want to construct.