# Return all INSTR or LOCATE instances in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, locate

I have a TEXT column containing a large amount of text (for arguments sake let's assume it's a novel). I need to use MySQL to locate certain words or phrases within the novel. Using INSTR or LOCATE will find a word or phrase and return the position (which is ideal), but it only returns the first instance, I need it to return all instances. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: and what is your code?

Comment: Do you need to know: 1) how many occurrences and where they are, 2) where they are, or 3) just how many occurrences?  Perhaps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: I need to know how many occurrences and where they are.