# How can I search multiple tables for value in a common column

Tags: mysql

I have a foreign key of "countyid" in multiple tables (52 to be exact) because 52 different objects in the software can be specific to a county (or it could be null, for all counties).

Without doing 52 "Unions", is there a way in MySQL to get the results in all 52 tables when I am looking for a specific countyid? (ie- looking up what I have in the DB for this particular county)

Or, to at least return the tables names which contain a record that has that certain countyid?

Comment: you can do a massive search, but .... an id is usually an integer which should be on a lot more tables than just the ones you are looking for

Comment: Sounds like your business logic compels you to join these things in as necessary, there's really no way around that.

Comment: Perfect use case for MongoDB :)  There are a few things you can do.  PHPMyAdmin has a search feature, spoken of here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database or, you can create that 52 table union and store it as a view for future reference, then just select out of that view like you had everything in one table.

Comment: Are you sure that there are 52 different kinds of thing?

Comment: There is no problem with doing 52 joins other than the typing of them, but just create a view for it once, and problem solved. No?

Comment: @Strawberry - Very sure. Forms can be for a particular county, Specific tasks can be for a certain county, Instructions on general tasks can be for a certain county, a Judge/Sheriff can only be in a specific county, etc.

Comment: what if the system is rolled out to another county? What if a counties subdivide or amalgamate. I'm not convinced that your design is sensible- but hey, it's your design

Comment: @Strawberry It's not my design and thanks for your concern but I'm not trying to (or need to) convince you of anything.